# Get maximum HSV values from image in emguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv, hsv

i'm trying to get maximum values of hue, saturation and value from image converted to hsv in C# using emguCV. In openCV i can use Vec3b but how i can get same effect in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is an direct equivalent. If you want the max of each channel you can split the HSV Mat into the 3 channels and the do a GetRangeValue which should return you the Max and Min for each channel.

```
    Mat orig = new Mat(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);

    using (Mat hsv = new Mat())
    {
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(orig, hsv, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv);
        Mat[] channels = hsv.Split();

        RangeF H = channels[0].GetValueRange();
        RangeF S = channels[1].GetValueRange();
        RangeF V = channels[2].GetValueRange();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Max H {0} Min H {1}", H.Max, H.Min));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Max S {0} Min S {1}", S.Max, S.Min));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Max V {0} Min V {1}", V.Max, V.Min));

        MCvScalar mean = CvInvoke.Mean(hsv);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Mean V {0} Mean S {1} Mean V {2} ", mean.V0, mean.V1, mean.V2)); ;
    }
```

Doug